# Laravel Backpack: Getting data from related table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, relationship, crud, laravel-backpack

I have DB with similar structure (i didnt show full structure):

```
users (id, name, comments)
company_user (id, company_id, user_id)
companies (id, name)
company_distributor (id, company_id, distributor_id)
distributors (id, name)
```

I have relations:

Company:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

public function distributors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Distributor')->withPivot('id')->whereNull('company_distributor.deleted_at');
    }
```

CompanyDistributor:

```
public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }

public function distributor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Distributor');
    }
```

When i try to get 'comments' from users - i get empty data, but request is right:

```
select users.*,company_user.company_id as pivot_company_id,company_user.user_id as pivot_user_id from users inner join company_user on users.id=company_user.user_id where company_user.company_id in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '7', '9', '10'........)
```

Crud in CompanyDistributorCrudController:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
            // 1-n relationship
            'label' => "Comments", 
            'type' => "select_multiple",
            'name' => 'company_id', 
            'entity' => 'company.users', 
            'attribute' => "comments", 
            'model' => "App\Models\Company", 
        ]);
```

What`s wrong ?

When i trying to add relation to CompanyDistributor:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->company->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

sql query getting 'id' from 'company_distributor' table but not 'company_id' that i need.

Sorry for my english

Comment: Your relationship is wrong. Take a look the table User and Company has no relationship at all (no key ), but you try to access user on company model. For other model are the same.

Comment: Relationship is many-to-many. Look at table company_user (id, company_id, user_id)

Comment: Yes, I know but you try to make relationship on user (return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');) is not on company_user.
it should be relationship with company_user model.

Comment: in company_user model you can make relationship to user.
in company model you can make relationship to company_user model.
now you can access like this : Company::companyUsers->user;